# Why two remove reference item are there for Model.remove in Mongoose API docs?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

After landing into the [API docs of mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-remove), there is left side menu, Under model.js section.
We see something like this:

```
- model.js

    -Model
    -save
    -increment
    -remove      <== 1
    -model
    -$where
    -ensureIndexes
    -remove      <== 2
    ...
```

Both **[remove](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-remove)** are having the link to `Model#remove([fn])`

There is one more topic which is not linked.
Titled `Model.remove(conditions, [callback])` which is documented under the same `model.js` section. (just after the topic [Model.ensureIndexes](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-ensureIndexes))

Could anyone one tell me what is the difference between both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always browse the [source code](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js) for mongoose. It's a great way to learn how it works.

There are two removes:

1. Model.prototype.remove => this removes a specific mongoose Model object from a collection. It works on an instance.

   `Model.prototype.remove = function remove (fn) { ... }`
2. Model.remove => this bypasses the Mongoose library and uses conditions supplied as the first parameter to perform a remove:

   `Model.remove = function remove (conditions, callback) { ... }`

(It is documented on the page as Model.remove, but it appears there's something wrong with the anchors on the page are pointed to the wrong function, likely because of the duplicated name.)