# Keep MongoDB connection open while running tests using mocha framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mocha.js

I'm using something akin to [How to properly reuse connection to Mongodb across NodeJs application and modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621940/how-to-properly-reuse-connection-to-mongodb-across-nodejs-application-and-module) to keep my mongoDB Connection open.
This requires all the code to go into a `MongoDB.connectDB(async (err) => {...}` Block.
How would I use this when writing Tests with Mocha.
Do I have to use a separate Connection for every test? Like this?

```
const MongoDB = require('../src/mongoUtil') // providing access to the mongo database
var events = require('../src/events') // containing all my database Functions

describe('events.js', function () {
  describe('addEvent()', function () {
    it('should return the event, when added succesfully', async function () {
      await MongoDB.connectDB(async (err) => {
        if (err) throw err

        const database = MongoDB.getDB()
        const eventsCollection = database.db().collection('events')

        const event = {
          name: 'test Event',
          members: []
        }

        const result = await events.addEvent(eventsCollection, event)

        MongoDB.disconnectDB()

        if (result.name !== event.name) {
          return new Error('TODO')
        }
      })
    })
  })
})
```

For this example to work properly I probably also have to manually set the test to done, if I understood the mocha website correctly?
Can I have just one connection?

mongoUtil.js

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/testing'

let _db

const connectDB = async (callback) => {
  try {
    MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {
      _db = db
      return callback(err)
    })
  } catch (e) {
    throw e
  }
}

const getDB = () => _db

const disconnectDB = () => _db.close()

module.exports = { connectDB, getDB, disconnectDB }
```

events.js

```
const addEvent = async (collection, event) => {
  try {
    const exists = await collection.findOne({ 'name': event.name })
    if (exists) {
      return false
    } else {
      const results = await collection.insertOne(event)
      return results.ops[0]
    }
  } catch (e) {
    throw e
  }
}
module.exports = { addEvent }
```

Comment: *Can I have just one connection?* - no. You may want to do this in `beforeEach` then.

Comment: I thought about that, but that's not possible since everything related to the database has to run inside a `MongoDB.connectDB({...})` Block.

Comment: What is inside `src/mongoUtil`?

Comment: I've added it to the main Post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put everything inside `MongoDB.connectDB({...})`. This is called callback hell which should be avoided when possible. `mongoUtil` is inconvenient wrapper that doesn't make MongoDB API simpler or easier to use.

`await MongoDB.connectDB(async (err) => { ...` is a mistake. Putting `async` function as a callback is not enough and will result in improper control flow.

`MongoClient.connect` uses error-first callbacks, so it can be used with `done` to pass errors to test suite:

```
let db;

beforeEach(done => {
  MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, _db) => {
    db = _db;
    done(err);
  });
});
```

`connectDB` incorrectly promisifies `MongoClient.connect`. There's no need for one-time callbacks when promises and `async..await` are in use. It could be:

```
const connectDB = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(db);
    });
  });
};
```

But the fact is that `mongodb` supports promises natively when callback argument is omitted. `mongoUtil` needs only one helper function, `connectDB`:

```
const connectDB = () => MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Which can be used with Mocha seamlessly since it supports promises:

```
let db;

beforeEach(async () => {
  db = await connectDB();
});

afterEach(() => db.close());
```

`close` is asynchronous and returns a promise, too.

Comment: This solved my issue, thank you. 
If I want to use the same solution in app.js, I'd need to wrap it into an async function and use await (like your beforeEach example) or use .then(). Could I just create a `const main = async () => {}` function?

Comment: You're welcome. A common recipe for app entry point now is async IIFE, `(async () => { ... })().catch(console.error)`.

Comment: Hi guys - I am in a similar situation and the solution you are discussing here seems to be closest one to what I want. However, I am having trouble getting it to work. Is it possible to provide a small example that shows both the code in the app.js file and in the test file? I am unable to get the test to exit, since it is not closing the Mongo connection and I don't know how to get the test to close it once it finishes running. I posted about this here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63759862/closing-a-mongodb-connection-after-running-mocha-tests-for-an-express-applicatio.

Comment: I am all set. Updated my question with the right answer.