# res.redirect() searching but not loading

Tags: node.js, express, post, request

i'm trying to redirect a user to a page after checking his credentials through a post method. the thing is the page after the res.redirect function keeps trying to redirect but never does.

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){

    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("DATABASE");

    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;


    dbo.collection("DATABASE").findOne({username: username, password: password}, function(err, user){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send();
        db.close();
      }
      if(!user){
        res.status(404).send();
        db.close();

      }else{
          console.log("gets here");
        app.get('/', function(req, res){
          res.redirect('/views/heap')

         });
      }
    })
  }); 
});
```

the console.log("gets here"); works perfectly fine but the redirect keeps on trying but never loading

Comment: Whats the `app.get('/', fu..` line?

Comment: Not related to the problem in the question, but "connecting to a database **within** each request" is simply **really bad**. Instead you should learn how to share the connection around your modular code. See : [How to properly reuse connection to Mongodb across NodeJs application and modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24621940/2313887)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
console.log("gets here");
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.redirect('/views/heap')

 });
```

To:

```
console.log("gets here");
res.redirect('/views/heap');
```

Comment: i changed the code but i get this error message: Cannot GET /views/heap.html

Comment: then the route doesn't exist, shouldn't it be `res.redirect('/login')`?

Comment: sidenote, you should also return on not found (first if statement) else your get headers already sent

Comment: thanks for your reply, it really helped, if I may also ask, what do you mean that i need to return on not found?

Comment: np, I mentioned it as you have 2 if blocks, once/if the first one fires because of the error, so will the `if(!user){` one as user wont be set, then your status()/send()'ing twice, which your not after, so need to return.