# Is there any easy way to copy collection data into another in MEAN app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm currently implementing admin dashboard of online shopping app.I want to implement method to perform user deletion and store that deleted user data temporally on another collection.

(Copy_userdata->Save it on another collection -> delete original data)

As an example my users data currently available in collection called users, and after deleting that user particular user's data must be available in another collection, lets say deleted_users collection. Are there any easy way to do that? thanks!

Comment: Your DB instance are same but only collection will be different? Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes i want perform on same db. only collection will be deference. I have no idea about what to do.

Comment: What is the version on mongodb server you are using?

Comment: @Sohan  db version v4.0.10
git version: c389e7f69f637f7a1ac3cc9fae843b635f20b766

Comment: You can use aggregate function and that will be the most efficient function.
Once you copy the data next step would be deleting or dropping original collection

Comment: In below function look at the aggregation function and query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be modify some of the code but this is the basic logic,

Use aggregation for copy collections over
Refer [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#aggregate) for aggregate function using mongo client

So the function looks like this

```
public aggregation(collectionName: string, pipelines: Object[]): Promise<Array<any>>
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        {
        let cursor: mongodb.AggregationCursor<any> = null;

             //Here you will use getCollection method on your own to fetch the collection
            this.getCollection(collectionName)
                .then((collection: mongodb.Collection) =>
                {
                    cursor = collection.aggregate(pipelines);

                    return cursor.toArray();
                })
                .then((result: Array<any>) =>
                {
                    return resolve(result);
                })
                .catch((error: any) =>
                { 
                    //error//
                });

    }

    public dropCollection(collectionName: string): Promise<any>
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        {

           this.getCollection(collectionName)
                .then((collection: mongodb.Collection) =>
                {
                    collection.drop((err: Error, result: any) =>
                    {

                        if (err)
                        {
                            return reject(DataDropError);
                        }

                        return resolve(result);
                    });
                })
                .catch(reject);
        });
    }

     public async backupAndDrop()
    {
        const Object = [ { $match: {} }, { $out: "DeletedCollection" } ];

        try
        {
            await this.aggregationPipeline("originalCollection", Object);
            await  this.dropCollection("originalCollection");

        }
        catch (e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

    }
```

Also try to run this on your mongo shell:

```
db.originalCollection.aggregate([ { $match: {} }, { $out: "Backup" } ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a flag like **isDeleted** which is false by default and then make it true when the user is deleted?

Comment: Thanks.yes, I also thought about it, but problem is if i add flag i also need to change my other codes too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

```
    Client.connect(connection_string, function(err, db) {
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       }
       else{
           db.collection(CollectionA).find().forEach(function(d){ db.collection(CollectionB).insert(d); });
        }
```

Try out if it works.

This can help too:
[How to properly reuse connection to Mongodb across NodeJs application and modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621940/how-to-properly-reuse-connection-to-mongodb-across-nodejs-application-and-module)

Comment: This will consume memory and it will be slow when you have millions of records in memory

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the record to be deleted and do a create with that data to the new collection and then delete the record.

```
db.collection(CollectionA).findOne({userIdTODelete}, function(err, res){ 
         db.collection(CollectionB).insertOne(res, function() { 
            db.collection(CollectionA).deleteOne({userIdTODelete}); 
    }) 
});
```