# Cannot find module Error While js files are located in same Directory

Tags: javascript, nodes

I have added a js Module called mongoUtil, which contains the code hereafter, following a suggestion found at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621940/how-to-properly-reuse-connection-to-mongodb-across-nodejs-application-and-module).

```
 const MongoClient = require( 'mongodb' ).MongoClient;
 const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

 var _db;

 module.exports = {
  connectToServer: function(callback) {
   MongoClient.connect(url,  {useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err, client) {
    _db  = client.db('MyDB');
    return callback(err);
   });
  },

  getDb: function() {
   return _db;
  }
 };
```

I have furthermore used the following line in my app.js Module:

```
const mongoUtil = require('mongoUtil')
```

However, I am obtaining the following error while the 2 Modules are located in the same Directory:

> Error: Cannot find module 'mongoUtil'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide a module name to `require` it will search `node_modules` for it.

If you want to read a module from the current directory, you need to use the file path. This can be relative: `require("./mongoUtil")`

Comment: Yes indeed! Thank you Quentin.

Answer (score 0):

The exact documentation is [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) including a (rather long) pseudocode explanation of how the algorithm of locating a module works.

But in short, there are two basic ways of loading a module:

- Using the name of an installed module (may be globally or locally installed), for example `require('mongodb')`. This would look for the (global or local) `node_modules/mongodb` folder.
- Using a path (absolute or relative), for example `require('./mongoUtil')`. This would look for a file at the given path - if it's relative, then it is relative to the current file.

So, the solution is to use `require('./mongoUtil')` and not `require('mongoUtil')`.

Comment: Thank you CherryDT.

Answer (score 0):

**This will work:**

```
const mongoUtil = require('./mongoUtil.js');
```

Or even just the following, since the extension is automatically resolved:

```
const mongoUtil = require('./mongoUtil');
```