# Trouble inserting array of documents into a database in mongodb via node js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to node js and mongodb. Just testing out some ideas so I am trying to create a web scraper that adds data to a database in mongodb. I have a script that connects to mongodb and dynamically adds data to the database through a node js script. I run this script in the console like so: 'node scrapeData.js' The script runs without any errors, but when I fire up the mongo shell and run db.posts.find(), I get 0 records. I know that my script is scraping the data successfully as it's logging the array of data in the console. Not sure where I'm going wrong. Here's my script:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


//requiring the module so we can access them later on
var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb', function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } 
    else {
        console.log("successfully connected to the database");

        //define url to download 
        var url = "http://www.nyxcosmetics.ca/en_CA/highlight-contour";

        var prodList = [];
        var priceList = [];
        var products = [];

        request(url, function(error, response, body) {
            if(!error) {


                //load page into cheerio
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);

                $(".product_tile_wrapper").each(function(i, elem) {
                    prodList[i] = $(this).find($(".product_name")).attr("title");
                    priceList[i] = $(this).find($(".product_price")).attr("data-pricevalue");
                });
                prodList.join(', ');

                for(var i = 0; i < prodList.length; i++) {
                    var prod = {
                        name: prodList[i], 
                        price: priceList[i]
                    };
                    products.push(prod);
                }

                console.log(products); //print the array of scraped data

                //insert the prods into the database
                //in the 'posts' collection
                var collection = db.collection('posts');
                collection.insert(products);
                console.log("products inserted into posts collection");

                //Locate all the entries using find
                collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
                    console.log(results);
                });

            } else {
                console.log("We've encountered an error!")
            }
        });
    }

    db.close();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a few hints:

- Can you check which mongodb NodeJS driver version are you using? [1.x](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html#and-then-there-was-crud) and [2.x](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/reference/crud/) are very different
- in 2.x driver version, `db.collection.insert()` is actually deprecated in favor of more verbose `.insertOne()` and `.insertMany()`
- you could debug what happened with your insert if you provide a write callback, e.g.

`collection.insert(products, function(error,result) {
 console.log(error);
 console.log(result);
})`

Comment: Thanks for your response! Turns out the version wasn't an issue. I debugged with your callback code above and I was getting an error like 'mongoError: Topology was destroyed'. It was to do with the db.close() statement. Apparently, I wasn't supposed to have that in the node js script. I'm really used to sql so closing a connection to db seemed normal to me but that's not good practice in mongodb. This post helped me as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425739/mongolab-nodejs-topology-destroyed