# MongoDB: Shall I keep a global session all the time?

Tags: mongodb, go

Here is a snippet of my DAO implementation:

```
type (
    User struct {
        Name string `json:"name" bson:"name"`
        ...
    }

    UserDAO struct {
        *mgo.Database
    }
)

func NewUserDAO() (*UserDAO, error) {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &UserDAO{session.DB("")}, nil
}

func (d *UserDAO) Insert(user User) error {
    return d.C("users").Insert(user)
}

func (d *CandleDAO) Find(name string) ([]User, error) {
    var result []User
    if err := d.C("users").Find(bson.M{"name": name)}).Sort("time").All(&result); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return result, nil
}

...

func (d *CandleDAO) Close() {
    d.Session.Close()
}
```

And here is how I invoke it:

```
dao, err := dao.NewUserDAO()
if err != nil {
    Log.Error(err.Error())
    return
}

// close session... is this OK?
defer dao.Close()

users, err := dao.Find(&broker.Symbol{"BTC", "USD"}); if err != nil {
    Log.Error(err.Error())
    return
}

for i, user := range users {
    fmt.Printf("%d ==> %v\n", i, user)
}
```

The code above works... and my question is simple: shall I keep a global `mgo.Database` instance or is it correct to always close the session when I'm finished and create a new one whenever I need?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [too many open files in mgo go server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179890/too-many-open-files-in-mgo-go-server/47180097#47180097); and [Concurrency in gopkg.in/mgo.v2 (Mongo, Go)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492020/concurrency-in-gopkg-in-mgo-v2-mongo-go/42495522#42495522); and [mgo - query performance seems consistently slow (500-650ms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40999637/mgo-query-performance-seems-consistently-slow-500-650ms/41000876#41000876).

Comment: I think that this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650890/keeping-open-a-mongodb-database-connection. In my case I'm using go and bigtable, and I am keeping the connection alive (unless/until the server crashes).

Comment: Ok thank you very much, really appreciated :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concurrency in gopkg.in/mgo.v2 (Mongo, Go)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492020/concurrency-in-gopkg-in-mgo-v2-mongo-go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [main package docs](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2):

> New sessions are typically created by calling session.Copy on the
>   initial session obtained at dial time. These new sessions will share
>   the same cluster information and connection pool, and may be easily
>   handed into other methods and functions for organizing logic. Every
>   session created must have its Close method called at the end of its
>   life time, so its resources may be put back in the pool or collected,
>   depending on the case.

Meaning: at startup you should `Dial` and save that session, and for each call to `NewUserDAO` you should `Clone` the initial `Session` created with `Dial`.