# "server sockets closed" when duplicate tabs are opened

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, express

I'm having trouble figuring out this issue.

I have a Node/Express server and I'm using MongoDB. Everything is working fine and normally. It has user accounts and the system for login and signup is working normally. I even tested signing up and logging in on my phone (I use Gulp as my build tool).

The problem I'm having now is that whenever I try to signup in the a duplicate tab (as in another tab on the same signup/login page) I get an error:

Server code:

```
//check for existing account using the given email
User.findOne({ "email" : email }, function(err, doc) {
    if(err) throw err;
    //if no email is found proceed with account creation
    if(!doc) {
        //snip
    } else {
        //if an account is found re-render the page with the error message
        //and close the db
        res.render(...);
        dbase.close();
    }
});
```

But when I have the same tab open I get this error:

```
MongoError: server localhost:27017 socket closed.
```

I've tested this multiple times. It works fine when there are no duplicate tabs. It works on my phone when the tab's still open on the computer. I checked and quadruple-checked to make sure I wasn't closing the DB too soon. This error literally only happens when I have the same tab open. when I submit the form they both start Loading (or attempting to, rather). Here's a screenshot to be very clear:

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/ad89b3df03ba9d44f203563f922893da.png]

Again, I've checked multiple times that I'm not closing the DB before receiving a response from the DB, and not outside of that response handle.

Am I missing something in my requests  handling? how can I keep it from sending data to both tabs and (seemingly) performing the same operation twice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you creating connection on every request? or is `dbase` is stored in a global scope?

Comment: Show us where you init dbase

Comment: More specifically you are calling `.close()` which you should generally never do. That is closing the database connection

Comment: @hassansin I'm creating a new connection every time. I wasn't sure if leaving the DB open is a good idea, though I've done it before.

Comment: @Louis93 This code block is happening inside where I open the DB. I open it for each connection where I need it.

Comment: The connection must be reused! More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14607887/765409

Comment: i.e. Don't close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Louis93 I have better clarity on how to construct my server an database queries.

> The connection must be reused! More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14607887/765409
>   i.e. Don't close it