# Mongo connection closed in keystonejs app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, keystonejs

For my keystonejs project I have created two docker containers (one for mongo, one for the keystonejs app). All works well, with the exception that I am getting very often a "connection closed" error when browsing the site (usually when I haven't navigated for a couple of minutes). The full error stack is below:

```
Error thrown for request: /blog
Error: connection closed
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:618:45)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at emit (events.js:166:7)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:171:15)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:550:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at TCP._onclose (net.js:477:12)
```

I have done some investigation, and another post on stackoverflow suggest to use the keepAlive option on mongoose ([mongoose output the error "Error: connection closed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928151/mongoose-output-the-error-error-connection-closed)). However, I have no idea how I can use these options in keystonejs. Can anybody help?

Best regards,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

In the [keystonejs docs](http://keystonejs.com/docs/configuration/), there is mention of

```
mongoose Object | Instance of Mongoose to be used instead of the default instance.
```

So spawning your own may work. I just pulled the options mentioned at [the answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31416167/2601448).

```
const mongoOptions =
{
    db: {safe: true},
    server: {
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 1
        }
    },
    replset: {
        rs_name: 'myReplSet',
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 1
        }
    }
};

mongoose.connect( YOUR_URI, mongoOptions );

keystone.set('mongoose', mongoose);
```

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what you are telling but it seems that I got it working

Answer (score 1):

I got it working like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.set('server', {
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 1
        }});

keystone.set('mongoose', mongoose);
```

Cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to configure mongoose options for keystone to use, you can do so without starting your own mongoose instance.

You can add mongoose / mongo options using the undocumented 'mongo options' property of the keystone config, eg

```
keystone.init({
    'mongo': 'yourMongoURI',
    'mongo options': { server: { keepAlive: 1 }}
});
```